# Finding rows with closest values to a given number

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe below which I will call "df":

```
idx      value
----     -----
0          1
1          1
2          1
3          0
4          2
5          3
6          4
7          4
8          5
9          6
```

And my value for example is:

```
my_value = 1
```

My goal is to get all rows closest to my_value which have the minimal absolute difference between df[value] - my_value.

In this case, for example, I have three rows that match, which are:

```
idx        value
-----     -------
0            1
1            1
2            1
```

These three rows have the same absolute difference that is zero and are the rows that I want to get.

I've been researching some functions like this:

```
df_result = df.iloc[(df['values'].sub(value)).abs().idxmin()]
```

But all the solutions that I have found only give me the number of rows that are indicated and fail in the case where the values are repeated.

For example for the above code just returns the index 0 of the first row and not the three indexes that contains the value of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that as follows:

```
query=1
# create a series with the absolute difference to your query value
ser_abs_diff= (df['value']-query).abs()

# extract the minimum
min_val= ser_abs_diff.min()

# apply it to your dataframe
df[ser_abs_diff==min_val]
```

With the following test data (note, that I changed row 5 to value 7 to make it a bit more interesting):

```
df= pd.DataFrame(dict(value=[1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 7, 4, 4, 5, 6]))
```

you get:

```
# with query=1
Out[82]: 
     value
idx       
0        1
1        1
2        1

# with query=3
Out[83]: 
     value
idx       
4        2
6        4
7        4
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a dif column and use groupby on dif and get the first group.

```
(
    df.assign(dif=df['value'].sub(my_value).abs())
    .groupby(by='dif', sort=True)
    .pipe(lambda x: next(iter(x))[1])
)
```

Comment: your answer fail for the next case: If I have the dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,0,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9],columns=['values'])
and my_value = 2 the expected results are 1,1,1,3,3 and your answer only gives me 1,1,1.

Comment: I get the next error AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sub'

Comment: You most likely used 'values' as a column name which is not a good idea as there is a pandas attribute called 'values'. Change the column name to 'value' or something else and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
min_diff = 0 
my_value = 1
pos_1 = my_value - min_diff
pos_2 = my_value + min_diff
min_accept = min(pos_1, pos_2)
max_accept = max(pos_1, pos_2)

df[df.values.between(min_accept, max_accept)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mad=0
my_value = 1
df.loc[(df['value'].sub(my_value).abs())== mad,'value']
```